# Rcpp: Cost of S4.slot()

Tags: r, rcpp, r-s4

I'm currently using S4 classes in a package with Rcpp and found a performance loss compared to an older version (less formal and less general) of my code to do the same task. I was wondering if there was a bottleneck caused by calling the `S4.slot()` function multiple times, so I created this example as a benchmark:

First define some S4 classes similar to what I'm using: `collection` is a class with a `itemlist` and some other meta information. `item` is a class with `subitems` that is a numeric vector and some other meta information.

```
setClass("collection", representation(itemlist = "list",
                                      element1 = "numeric",
                                      element2 = "character"))

setClass("item", representation(subitems = "numeric",
                                subitemnames = "character"))

a_item = new("item", subitems = c(1,2),
                      subitemnames = c("A","B"))

a_collection = new("collection", itemlist = replicate(1000000, a_item),
                                 element1 = 123, element2 = "something")
```

I'm trying to operate on the a `collection` object using all of its `itemlist`. So I created an Rcpp function to `sum` all the elements of each `itemlist` and add them together.

```
cfn_s4 <-
  'double operation(S4 collection, NumericVector z){
    double res = 0;
    List all_items = collection.slot("itemlist");
    for(int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++){
      S4 this_item = all_items[i];
      NumericVector to_add = this_item.slot("subitems");
      res = res + sum(to_add)*z[i];
    }
    return(res);
  }'
```

I also created another version that does the same, but takes a `list` as argument (no S4 is used here). Some pre-processing is required, I lose some meta information, but there is no need to call `S4.slot` here.

```
cfn_list <-   
'double operation_list(List collection, NumericVector z){
    double res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++){
      NumericVector to_add = collection[i];
      res = res + sum(to_add)*z[i];
    }
    return(res);
  }'
```

Here are the benchmarks:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(rbenchmark)
fn_s4 <- cppFunction(cfn_s4)
fn_list <- cppFunction(cfn_list)

set.seed(1)
z <- rnorm(1000)

ready_list <- map(a_collection@itemlist, "subitems")

benchmark(fn_s4(a_collection, z),
          fn_list(ready_list, z))
                    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 fn_list(ready_list, z)          100    0.00       NA      0.00        0         NA        NA
1 fn_s4(a_collection, z)          100    0.01       NA      0.02        0         NA        NA
```

Even for a `collection` object with a list of a million elements, the times made me think that even with a million `S4.slot` calls, there was no performance hit in the function, so the cost of `S4.slot` is negligible. Is this actually the case? I thought using S4 classes, specially when Rcpp has no idea what they actually are, should make the code slower due to some possible type conversions required.

Can I trust this benchmark and assume there is no significant performance loss caused by calling `S4.slot` even millions of times? Can you see something wrong with my functions leading to unfair comparisons?

Comment: S4 is orthogonal to Rcpp.  You can use it, or not use -- either with or without Rcpp.  I don't see what this question has to do with Rcpp.  _You are simply calling S4 semantics from different entry points_.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel! I just wanted to make sure there was no extra costs included with the interaction of S4 and Rcpp.